# Unable to get the proper multi-class ROC Curve using the pROC library in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, roc

My prediction column has spam, not spam and undefinable. I used the ensemble method-stacking method to predict it.I was able to get an accuracy of around 77% I am able to plot the ROC Curve but I just don't think it is right.

Ensemle Technique code:

```
# Generate level-one dataset for training the ensemble metalearner
predDF <- data.frame(dataTest.pred, NB_Predictions, RF_Predictions,SVM_Predictions, spam = validation$spam, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Train the ensemble

# define training control
set.seed(1958)
# Train the ensemble
modelStack <- caret::train(spam ~ ., data = predDF, method = "rf")
```

Here is my code for the ROC:

```
#ROC Curve
pre<-predict(modelStack, testPredLevelOne,type='prob')
# AUC measure
modelroc = mean(
  c(as.numeric(multiclass.roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre[,1])$auc),
    as.numeric(multiclass.roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre[,2])$auc),
    as.numeric(multiclass.roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre[,3])$auc)
  )
)
```

I don't think the AUC measure is also right.

```
> modelroc
[1] 0.500903
```

Here is another method that I tried to plot the ROC curve. I don't think that is working either.

```
#Method 2 ROC
predictions<-as.numeric(predict(modelStack, testPredLevelOne))
roc.multi<-multiclass.roc(testPredLevelOne$spam,predictions)
auc(roc.multi)
rs <- roc.multi[['rocs']]
plot.roc(rs[[1]])

sapply(2:length(rs),function(i) lines.roc(rs[[i]],col=i))
```

Here is the Plot:

[image]

Could someone please help me out with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the `auc` value is in line with the plot. It definitely not a good model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The averaging between the classes is done directly within pROC. Therefore you want to run `multiclass.roc` only once, with a single vector of predictions. Typically you want to use `type="response"` instead of `probs`, although this may vary depending on the `predict` function available for your model:

```
pre<-predict(modelStack, testPredLevelOne, type='response')
```

After that, pROC does the averaging for you so you can get the average AUC directly:

```
multiclass.roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre)$auc
```

Note that in your case this will be the average over 3 AUCs: spam vs. not spam, spam vs. undefinable and not spam vs. undefinable. This may not reflect the value of accuracy you calculated.

Regarding the plot, you obtained the predicted class from the `predict.train` method from caret. Usually in order to construct a ROC curve, you want a numeric, quantitative measurement. A qualitative measurement results in a ROC curve containing a single point, which is usually not optimal. Unfortunately the `type="probs"` option from caret returns 3 vectors of probabilities, which is not a format supported by pROC.

An alternative would be to do perform the calculation more manually, selecting the correct probability column and levels you want to test:

```
pre<-predict(modelStack, testPredLevelOne,type='prob')
roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre[,X], levels = c("not spam", "spam"), plot = TRUE)
roc(testPredLevelOne$spam, pre[,X], levels = c("undefined", " spam"), plot = TRUE, add = TRUE)
```

Ultimately, you should carefully review the relevance of multiclass ROC analysis. ROC was designed for binary classification, and the relevance of the various existing multiclass extensions is somewhat dubious in my experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  Is it right the way I have plotted it using my second method? Would you be to let me know on how to go about plotting this? I am new to data mining trying to learn my way through. I have done it for binary classes but never for muti-classes. Just struggling a bit. Would be a big help. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: @TheAsipiringone it's hard to say without knowing what method was used by `predict` (in other words how you generated `modelStack`) or what is in the `predictions` variable really. You need to give more details in your question if you want more than a general answer (mine here would be: it looks OK to me).

Comment: The ensemble technique was built using C4.5, Naive Bayes, SVM and Random Forest. I have added my code for generating modelstack.

Comment: Ok so you are using the `?caret:::predict.train` function. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Calimo what is X in the code?